# VBA - Wait for formulae dependant on PivotTable to update before proceeding

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

As per the title, looking to wait for formulae dependent on PivotTable to update before proceeding.

**The set up (in Excel 2010 workbook):**

1. PivotTable constructed with

   - One xlDataField (unchanging),
   - Several xlRowFields (unchanging), and
   - One xlPageField (for changing via VBA, to increase speed of data retrieval)
2. Two-dimensional range (columns x rows) populated using formulae (including GetPivotData derived from the above PivotTable)

**Processing (via VBA):**

3. The above mentioned xlPageField is changed (expecting the values in
   the above mentioned range are updated)
4. Two-dimensional range “read” into a Variant for further processing via VBA

The process is falling over between the steps 3 and 4.  The range values are not updated before being read into a Variant.  It could be the PivotTable is not updating, the formulae dependant on the PivotTable are not updating, or both.

Solutions attempted to date (from various StackOverlow threads or external websites):

- `PivotTables("*name*").PivotCache.BackgroundQ‌​uery = False` ([Getting Excel VBA to wait for external workbook links to refresh before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220468/getting-excel-vba-to-wait-for-external-workbook-links-to-refresh-before-continui)).  Results in Run-time error '1004'.
- `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll
  DoEvents` ([Wait until ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll finishes - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba)) No impact.
- And a mix of:

  - `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    DoEvents`
  - `PivotTables("*name*").RefreshTable
    DoEvents`
  - `Application.Calculate
    DoEvents`
  - `Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
    DoEvents
    Loop` ([Wait until Application.Calculate has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277034/wait-until-application-calculate-has-finished))

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Requested code (truncated)

```
Dim AllocationRange As Variant
Dim SwitchHistory As PivotTable

Sub Main()
    InitialisePublicVariables

    'For each member
        GetMemberSwitchHistory
        Dim Allocations As New Dictionary: Set Allocations = GetDictionary("Allocations")
    // further processes
    'Next member
End Sub

Private Sub InitialisePublicVariables()
    Set SwitchHistory = Sheets("All Switches (clean)").PivotTables("SwitchHistory")
    AllocationRange = Range("AllocationRange")
End Sub

Private Sub GetMemberSwitchHistory()
    Dim MemberAccountNumber As String: MemberAccountNumber = Range("MemberAccountNumber").Value
    SwitchHistory.PivotFields("Member Account Number").CurrentPage = MemberAccountNumber
    SwitchHistory.RefreshTable
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Regards
Shannon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you refactor your code so that you can use the `PivotTableUpdate` event on the `Worksheet` to operate on the Pivot after it is updated?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

  Debug.Print "Pivot table updated - do stuff..."

End Sub
```

You can also use the `PivtoTableChangeSync` event (this may be more appropriate as it discerns changes more).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

  Debug.Print "Pivot table change sync..."

End Sub
```

More information on this event can be found here:-  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838251.aspx

Comment: The xlPageField is changed some 2,500 times as part of a wider loop.  I believe Worksheet_PivotTableChangeSync() would result in asynchronous code and more problems.

Comment: Can you post the actual code block that is failing?  What is the data type of the Page field you are setting the value for?

Comment: A failing code block would be: `Dim SwitchHistory As PivotTable
Set SwitchHistory = Sheets("name").PivotTables("SwitchHistory")
SwitchHistory.PivotCache.BackgroundQuery = False` resulting in Run-time '1004'. However, the overall (lengthy) code does not fail, it simply returns an incorrect result due to the failed refresh/update.  Should the code be run twice or more on the same xlPageField the result is correct (due to no required update on the PivotTable or dependent formulae.

Comment: That isn't enough. You need to show all of the code in steps 3 & 4 so I can see what is really happening